# Is it bad to have 100+ classes in one element

Tags: html, css

I am making some website and I thought if I make css for everything as each class it can be easier to change after something like extended bootstrap...

So I would have `font-size.css, text_colors.css etc`

```
.1px{font-size: 1px;} .2px{font-size: 2px;}....
.red{color: red;} .B4040{color: #B40404;}....
```

And then when I make div:

```
<div class="2px B40404 something_else"></div>
```

Comment: In current form your post is asking for code style opinions which is off-topic on SO. You may come up with concrete criteria to decide "good vs. bad" (like particular browser performance, size, ...), note that "easy to read"/ "easy to maintain" would not be good criteria for SO question.

Answer (score 1):

this is really a bad idea, like if you were using the `style` attribute :

```
<div style="width:50px;"></div>
```

Classes are meant to be useful, you'd loose your time doing that.
And in my opinion (others will tell if they disagree), the way a CMS etc works is awful.